# Periodically update a table with new records from another legacy server

Tags: sql-server

Periodically update a table A in new server with new records or updated record from another legacy server. / also I only need to insert updated or new records in selected columns every few hours or few sec is this possible.

Comment: Too Broad to answer. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this.

SSIS is one good way, then schedule with SQL Agent.

Or create a stored procedure to copy the data from the legacy server into a temp table then MERGE into the new tables.  Schedule this with SQL Agent.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you please provide the ssis component that I have to use or step by step process. or the store procedure syntax where i can edit my stuff and then the merge command. Greatly appropriate your help.